# Get the `pwd` in an `alias`?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

Is there a way I can get the `pwd` in an `alias` in my `.zshrc` file? I'm trying to do something like the following:

```
alias cleanup="rm -Rf `pwd`/{foo,bar,baz}"
```

This worked fine in bash; `pwd` is always the directory I've `cd`'d into, however in zsh it seems that it's evaluated when the `.zshrc` file is first loaded and always stays as my home directory. I've tested using with a really simple `alias` setup, but it never changes.

How can I have this change, so that calling the `alias` from a subdirectory always evaluates as that subdir?

**EDIT:** not sure if this will help, but I'm using zsh via oh-my-zsh on the mac.

Comment: Hm, anything wrong with using a function instead? `function pwdtestf(){echo `pwd`}` appears to work?

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz pwd is only worked in function instead of alias script. My ENV: iTerm2 + ohmyzsh

Answer (score 42, accepted):

When your `.zshrc` is loaded, the `alias` command is evaluated. The command consists of two words: a command name (the builtin `alias`), and one argument, which is the result of expanding `` cleanup="rm -Rf `pwd`/{foo,bar,baz}" ``. Since backquotes are interpolated between double quotes, this argument expands to `cleanup=rm -Rf /home/unpluggd/{foo,bar,baz}` (that's a single shell word) where `/home/unpluggd` is the current directory at that time.

If you want to avoid interpolation at the time the command is defined, use single quotes instead. This is almost always what you want for aliases.

```
alias cleanup='rm -Rf `pwd`/{foo,bar,baz}'
```

However this is needlessly complicated. You don't need `` `pwd/` `` in front of file names! Just write

```
alias cleanup='rm -Rf -- {foo,bar,baz}'
```

(the `--` is needed if `foo` might begin with a `-`, to avoid its being parsed as an option to `rm`), which can be simplified since the braces are no longer needed:

```
alias cleanup='rm -Rf -- foo bar baz'
```

Comment: This is the sort of amazing answer you only get on SO! Thanks Gilles!