# Zsh alias always sets $PWD to home

Tags: bash, zsh, tmux, zshrc

I want to alias a command that creates a new tmux session in the folder I'm currently in, and sets the folder name (hyphenated) as the session name. If the session already exists, tmux attaches to it:

```
alias tses="tmux new -As $(basename $PWD | tr . -)"
```

When I run the command in my shell like so: `tmux new -As $(basename $PWD | tr . -)` it works as expected. But when I run the alias `tses`, it always sets the name of my home folder as the session name.

Why is that and how can I fix it to work as expected?

Comment: 99% of problems with aliases can be solved by using a function instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently, the double quotes cause zsh to evaluate the command (and thus `$PWD`) when `.zshrc` is loaded. Putting it in single quotes:

```
alias tses='tmux new -As $(basename $PWD | tr . -)'
```

solved it. See also: [Get the `pwd` in an `alias`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566078/get-the-pwd-in-an-alias).