# unable to access terminal alias/ shortcuts in .zshrc file or .bashrc in terminal, File/folder permission issue

Tags: git, macos, alias

On mac, it used to work file but recently it doesnt allow me to use the alias /shortcuts in the terminal

I have created the alias for git add .   =  a . 
git checkout -b  = co -b 
But now unless I specify sudo and full git add .  command i can't run the command.

Also for any command I always have to use sudo which wasn't the case before.

projectFolder/.git: Permission denied
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Unless I do sudo and full git iniit  command it doesnt work. 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have access to sudo, you should be able to chown your all tree back to your account:

```
sudo chown -R jay /Users/jay
```

As long as you see root as a user in your tree (with `ls -alrth`), you would need sudo indeed.

Comment: It says: "  : Operation not permitted "

Comment: @JP. Sorry, I forgot the sudo. See my edited answer.

Comment: How can i create a shortcut / alias so that i can give this permission to my current folder or  pwd folder. ?

Comment: @JP. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5573447/6309. You don't need pwd. Your alias would execute itself in the current directory anyway. But if you must have pwd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/39835/7490