# Build entity name by concatenating pwd and string in bash alias

Tags: bash, alias

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5573447/2223106) is insightful but I'm still struggling a bit.

What I want is to create an alias that I can use to backup a mysql database in a docker container.

The Container names in this case are a concatination of the working directory and a text string: `directory_name_1`.

The command I want to run ([github gist](https://gist.github.com/spalladino/6d981f7b33f6e0afe6bb)) is this:

```
docker exec CONTAINER /usr/bin/mysqldump -u root --password=root DATABASE > backup.sql
```

Which puts the backup file in the Working Directory.

I have tried

```
alias dumpdb='docker exec `pwd`_my-string mysqldump -uroot --password=password DATABASE > `pwd`/backup.sql'
```

And variations on

`` alias WORKING_DIR="pwd | rev | cut -d "/" -f1 | rev"
alias DOCKER_CONTAINER='echo $(WORKING_DIR)_my-wpdb_1'
alias dumpdb='docker exec $(DOCKER_CONTAINER) mysqldump -uroot --password=password DATABASE > `pwd`/backup.sql' ``

But I'm still poking around in the dock. Would someone be so kind as to guide me?

Comment: is it mandatory to use an alias? It is also possible by creating a function.

Comment: you mean like a bash script, which then I could theoretically create an alias to? I just want to streamline the process.

Comment: `>$(pwd)/backup.sql` is the same as `>./backup.sql` which is the same as `>backup.sql`.  I don't see your problem regarding the location of the backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good solution would be to use a function (and not an alias).

**Why?** 
Because alias are supposed to be used only for simple modifications (like adding an extra argument/flag to commands).

Hence, we can either create a function, or a shellscript. In our case, since it's a pretty simple problem, we can just create a function.

You should write it on .bash_profile

So, for example, you might try to define the following function

```
function dumpdb()
{
    local wkdir="basename $(pwd)"
    local container="${wkdir}_my-wpdb_1"
    docker exec ${container} mysqldump -uroot --password=password DATABASE > backup.sql
}
```

After writing that, and reloading your bash_profile (either using source .bash_profile or creating a new session) you will be able to execute dumpdb on console just like if it was an alias.

Answer (score 2):

```
dumpdb () {
   docker exec "${PWD##*/}_my-wpdb_1" \
       mysqldump -uroot --password=password DATABASE >backup.sql
}
```

Or, as an alias:

```
alias dumpdb='docker exec "${PWD##*/}_my-wpdb_1" \
    mysqldump -uroot --password=password DATABASE >backup.sql'
```

By using a function, you could pass it the database name, for example:

```
dumpdb () {
   docker exec "${PWD##*/}_my-wpdb_1" \
       mysqldump -uroot --password=password "$1" >backup.sql
}

dumpdb "my_database"
```

`${PWD##*/}` will expand to the basename of the parent working directory; if `$PWD` is `/home/user/stuff`, then `${PWD##*/}` will be `stuff`.

If you don't specify a directory name for the file that you redirect to, the file will end up in the current working directory, so using `pwd` is not necessary.

Comment: Thank you. I accepted the other answer 'cause it came first and he seems like he could use the points more than you. Both really useful. I imagine that one could extend to also accept `$2` and `$3` and use `if` statements to populate variables if parameters not given?

Comment: @MikeiLL Yes, you can do pretty much whatever you want inside a function.

Comment: Seems like the `~/.bashrc` could get rather lengthy. What do people generally do if they want to load different sets of functions, aliases for different workflows?

Comment: @MikeiLL Put them in separate files and source these when needed, or from `.bashrc`?

Comment: One could just make any arbitrary file like `~/.python_bash` and then do `source ~/.python_bash`, for example?

Comment: @MikeiLL Absolutely.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation for commenting and Kusalananda's answer is just perfect.

For anyone who needs more universal solution this is a little tweak for the answer of Kusalananda.

```
dumpdb () {
   docker exec "$1" \
      mysqldump -uroot --password=secret "$2" > sql/dump.sql
}
```

This way you can pass 2 arguments. One for the container and one for the database name.

You can call the function simply:
dumpdb example_container_1 database

If you want to give further arguments just put $3, $4, etc and call the function dumpdb arg1 arg2 arg3 arg4 etc